# SAS Encoding Label

Tags: character-encoding, sas, enterprise-guide

I have a dataset x. When I try the following code it gives me the following error.

```
libname raw 'D:\Apellis\data\raw' outrep='WINDOWS_64';

data x;
set raw.x;
run;

ERROR: Some character data was lost during transcoding in the dataset WORK.X. Either the data contains characters that are not 
       representable in the new encoding or truncation occurred during transcoding.
```

If I try the following inencoding option the error disappears from the log, however, *would this result in some rows being omitted?*:

```
libname raw 'D:\Apellis\data\raw' outrep='WINDOWS_64' inencoding=any;

    data x;
    set raw.x;
    run;
```

Additionally, I figured, the raw.x dataset has a variable which contains the following character ***â‰¥***, which I think could be leading to the encoding problem. Do Labels containing such characters also lead to the encoding error described above? How do I get rid of this?

Comment: I don't see why you would loose data this way.